# Updating UserDefaults after setting

Tags: swift, swift5

I am defining here my values for UserDefaults. With the next start my apps opens the correct window. But I also want to update the UserDefaults right after setting them. So that I can use them now.

```
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
  @IBAction func pressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        switch team {
        case "bayernMunchen":
        defaults.set(46, forKey: "MannschaftsAuswahl")
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
        case "borussiaDortmund":
        defaults.set(41, forKey: "MannschaftsAuswahl")
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
        case "schalke":
        defaults.set(45, forKey: "MannschaftsAuswahl") 
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
        default: print(8)
        }
        let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
        let nextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "WeatherViewController") as! WeatherViewController
        self.present(nextViewController, animated:true, completion:nil)
    }
```

My code above opens another window and I try to get the value with this:

```
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
var cityName = defaults.integer(forKey: "MannschaftsAuswahl")
print(cityName)
```

But it doesnt show me the updated value. As I said I need to close and open the app.
How can I update UserDefaults after setting them?

Comment: There's a `synchronize` function for `UserDefaults`

Comment: Your code is fine, so there must be more going on that you have not told us. But do not use UserDefaults to pass a value to the next view controller. Pass the value, itself, directly to the new view controller.

Comment: I have to correct myself. Synchronize did not work. I just thought so. I dont know what I did wrong. I updated the code above.

Comment: matt I don't know how to set a value for a variable within a function. I read this doesn't work.

Comment: koropok thank you but it didn't work.

Comment: @koropok No need to use `synchronize`, ever. It's mentioned in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults/1414005-synchronize) : "this method is unnecessary and shouldn't be used".

Comment: why do you suggest me to use it then?

Comment: @PeterMeier well you can simply assign the value to your nextViewController before presenting it, assuming that's where you are trying to get it.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I update UserDefaults after setting them?

If you want to reset UserDefaults then:

```
UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "MannschaftsAuswahl")
```

From what I understand, you are trying to store the Int value of based team in one view controller and access that Int Value in another view controller to which you can performing segue. You can do as below:
Let say you have 2 View controllers (MainVC) where you have image and create order button and (WeatherViewController) which will be presented when "Pressed" button is clicked. So you want team data from MainVC to be accessed in WeatherViewController then in you can do below:

In MainVC:

```
class MainVC : UIViewController {
   var teamData : Int = 0
   ....
   @IBAction func pressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
      switch team {
         case "bayernMunchen":
           self.teamData = 46
         case "borussiaDortmund":
           self.teamData = 41
         case "schalke":
           self.teamData = 45
         default: print(8)
      }
      self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showWeatherViewController", sender: self)
   }
    
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.destination is WeatherViewController
        {
            let vc = segue.destination as? WeatherViewController
            vc?.mannschaftsAuswahl = teamData
        }
    }
}
```

And in WeatherViewController.swift, you have to declare imageDataArray as below and when you perform segue from MainVC to WeatherViewController this imageDataArray will now contain all the imageData array content of MainVC and you can access these:

```
 class SecondVC : UIViewController {
     var mannschaftsAuswahl : Int
     ...
     func printCityName() {
         print(mannschaftsAuswahl)
     }
 }
```

UPDATE:
Even if you use UINavigationController you can use segue. Add a segue of kind "show( e.g push)" from the button you want to click in your storyboard to WeatherManager ViewController and add an identifier showWeatherViewController the above code will work as expected.

Comment: Hey thanks. Yes that what I want to to. But I don't use segues. I use UINavigationController and use this code to change to the next screen with click on button: let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
        let nextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "WeatherViewController") as! WeatherViewController
        self.present(nextViewController, animated:true, completion:nil)  But the Int I use in another swift file. The Swift File is called WeatherManager.swift

Comment: Even if you use UINavigationController you can use segue. Add a segue of kind "show( e.g push)"  from the button you want to click in your storyboard to WeatherManager ViewController and add an identifier **showWeatherViewController**  the above code will work as expected.

Comment: This leads me to another problem. I can only attach on segue to a view. But right now I have 2 windows attached with an if else statement to that view.

Comment: You can attach segue from view controller also ,not only view. I didn't understand what you meant by 2 windows attached, you mean 2 more segue ? If so , then you can distinguish them by their identifiers (make sure the identifiers of each segue are unique) and you can include one more else if statement to call this segue "showWeatherViewController"